# Need to update a table from the result of other table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

We have two tables, `Users` and `History`.

`Users` table has the following columns

| Users | Active |
| --- | --- |
| A | Y |
| B | Y |
| C | Y |
| X | Y |
| Y | Y |
| Z | Y |

`History` table has the following columns

| users | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| A | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| B | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| C | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| B | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| A | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| X | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| Y | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |

From the `History` table, we are querying users who are active since last six months using following query

```
SELECT 
    users, 
    MAX(CAST(start_date) AS date) AS "start", 
    MAX(CAST(end_date) AS date) AS "end" 
FROM 
    history 
WHERE 
    start > 'DD-MMM-YYY' 
GROUP BY 
    users
```

This is retrieving the following details

| users | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| X | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |
| Y | DD-MMM-YY | DD-MMM-YY |

Now based on this details i want to change the `Active` column in the `Users` table and set it from Y to N  for the users not retrieved from second query.

Output should be like this

| Users | Active |
| --- | --- |
| A | Y |
| B | N |
| C | N |
| X | Y |
| Y | Y |
| Z | N |

Can some please help to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` such as

```
UPDATE users u
   SET active = 'N'
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                      FROM history 
                     WHERE startdate >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '6' MONTH
                       AND users = u.users)
```

where non-matched records for individual users are updated to be inactive.
<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99c1b06ab9eee6fb0f1c3d9539975375)</kbd>

Comment: Hello Thank you for the response,
I was trying to select the list of users before proceeding with the update to validate it but i was able to select even the users which i didn't wanted to
is there a way i can select the users before updating to validate it once please..

Comment: you're welcome @RaahithyaAnik . I couldn't understand your question well. Can you please describe with an example by editing the question.

Comment: Hello, Yes i was trying to do the select query before the update but seems like list selected was also having the user which ideally should not as per my requirement, i don't know if i am doing something wrong in the selection query 
so can you please help me with select query to first cross verify the results that i will later update using the query provided by you earlier @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: Can some one please help me with this..? this is little urgent for us.. Would be a great help